# FreeBSD-11 Installing a font results in invisible text in LibreOffice

Tags: freebsd, fontconfig, ttf

I installed a freeware .ttf font on my FreeBSD-11.1 workstation where I use Mate as the GDM.  The font was installed by copying the .ttf file to `/usr/local/share/fonts/TTF` and running `fc-cache -vf`.

The font name shows up in the fonts available drop-down menu in LO.

However, if I select an entire line and change the font to the newly installed one then the line simply disappears.  If, instead, I select a sub-string of a line then the font displays the text, but in a very, very tiny font size.

Have I missed something in installing this font?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I use: `mkfontscale /usr/local/share/fonts/TTF`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and it made no difference.  I think that there must be something odd about the font file itself.  I have located the same font file from multiple sources and get the same results with each copy.  But I do not get this problem with any other fonts I install at the same time.

Comment: I once bought a collection of a couple hundred or so fonts, of varying quality. One that I actually liked would display fine when installed on OS X, but not at all on Linux. I don't know what properties were treated so differently by the two OSes, but this can happen